# End to end profiling of nodejs REST Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling, v8

I have written a Nodejs api that will be accessed using 5000 concurrent requests.
I have test the api using Jmeter for 5000 concurrent users. The api is taking very little time initially but after 1000 request it takes 2 seconds to complete the request. The api code execution time is 400ms calculated by time difference of start and end of request.

Is there a way I can check how much time API request is spending in the event loop waiting for other requests to complete? Any tool that can help end to end profiling of the API?

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "how much time Api request is spending in the event loop waiting for other requests to complete"?

Comment: Basically I want to figure out the code block that is blocking the event loop or slowing the API if there is large number of concurrent requests. So is there any tool that can help me figure out complete tracing and profiling of the API?

Currently the machine where code is hosted is Quad core with 8GB RAM and I am using node cluster module to run code in all cores. So 5000 concurrent requests should not be an issue?

Comment: It depends entirely upon how much CPU time each request takes as to whether you can handle 5000 concurrent requests without an increasing delay and whether you have any shared access to data that might be a bottleneck, regardless of CPU.  I've seen reference to some such tools before for helping characterize this, but don't have the names.  FYI, asking only for 3rd party tools is considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js supports profiling with the `--prof` flag, see e.g. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/ (as well as a bunch of other documentation and tutorials all around the internet). That doesn't answer "what did this particular request do or wait for?", but it does answer "what did the node process spend its time doing?" -- hopefully both questions have the same answer.

In addition to that, I would suggest to simplify your setup in order to narrow down what's going on. If you run only on one core (with fewer requests), does the issue still happen? If you reduce the number of concurrent requests, does the issue still happen? In the extreme, if you send requests serially, does the issue still happen? The more you can simplify things, the easier you'll be able to tell what's going on.

It could be that your implementation is leaking some resource (memory, file handlers, whatever), making things slower over time. It could be that 5000 concurrent requests are simply more than your quadcore can handle.